# PySpark - create a boolean column without using a for loop

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a table with 2 indicators regarding annual deaths registered by country.
Here is a sample:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("deathCount").getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (2021, 657000, 970.0, "France"),
    (2020, 668922, 990.0, "France"),
    (2019, 613243, 910.0, "France"),
    (2020, 608002, 1016.2, "UK"),
    (2019, 530841, 893.1,  "UK"),
], schema='Year integer, Deaths integer, deathRatep100k double, Country string')
```

By the way, for the 2 countries listed above, here are my sources:

- France: [INSEE](https://www.insee.fr/fr/statistiques/fichier/2383440/demo-deces-taux-mort.xlsx)
- UK: [ONS](https://www.ons.gov.uk/aboutus/transparencyandgovernance/freedomofinformationfoi/deathsintheukfrom1990to2020)

I want to select only countries that has comparable figures from one year to another on the whole period.

What I mean by comparable is the figures are within a certain interval from one year to another.

For instance, if I take the number of deaths for year N and compare it to the number of deaths in year N+1,
the year N+1 is comparable to year N if it is within a range between 80% and 120% of year N.

Here is the code I use to achieve that in PySpark:

```py
# Creation of a blank sparkSQL DataFrame (yearEvol) that will be fed by a for loop
columns = ['country', 'yearN', 'yearN1', 'Period', 'Comparable']
# creation of a blank table, with one dummy row to infer schema
yearEvol = spark.createDataFrame(data = [("",0.0,0.0,"",True)], schema=columns)
# we take every distinct countries and store it in a list through collection process
countryList = [row.Country for row in df.select('Country').distinct().collect()]

# for each year and country, we take the number of deaths in year N, the number of death in year N+1
# and a we create a boolean of whether the yearN+1 value is between 80% and 120% of year N or not
for country in countryList:
    dfCountry = df.where(f"Country = \"{country}\"")
    # Pivot table with the year in columns, the countries in index, and the number of deaths in values
    deathPivot = dfCountry.groupBy('Country').pivot('Year').sum('Deaths')
    # Extractions of the years range in columns of deathPivot, sorted and stored in a list
    deathYears_sorted = [int(col) for col in filter(lambda x: x != "Country", list(deathPivot.columns))]
    for col in deathYears_sorted[:-1]:
        yearNname, yearN1name = (str(col), str(col+1))
        yearN, yearN1 = (F.col(yearNname), F.col(yearN1name))
        # if the period in years is not continuous, ie for each year N if year N+1 column is missing,
        # create that column and assign it the value 0.0
        if yearN1name not in deathPivot.columns:
            deathPivot = deathPivot.withColumn(yearN1name, F.lit(0.0))
        # create an intermediary table for each country, and yearN-N+1 period,
        # which will be unioned with the blank yearEvol table
        x = (deathPivot.select('Country', yearN, yearN1)
                       .withColumnRenamed(yearNname, 'yearN')
                       .withColumnRenamed(yearN1name,'yearN1')
                       .withColumn('Period', F.lit(f"{col}-{col+1}"))
                       .withColumn('Comparable', 
                                   F.when(F.col('yearN1').between(.8*F.col('yearN'), 1.2*F.col('yearN')),
                                          F.lit(True)).otherwise(F.lit(False))))
        yearEvol = yearEvol.union(x)
yearEvol = yearEvol.filter(F.col('Country') != "") # Filters the dummy blank line required to create the table
```

My aim is to filter the `yearEvol` table on countries on which the false count is nil for the `Comparable` column.

Here is the output of `yearEvol.show()`:

```py
+-------+--------+--------+---------+----------+
|country|   yearN|  yearN1|   Period|Comparable|
+-------+--------+--------+---------+----------+
| France|613243.0|668922.0|2019-2020|      true|
| France|668922.0|657000.0|2020-2021|      true|
|     UK|530841.0|608002.0|2019-2020|      true|
+-------+--------+--------+---------+----------+
```

Eventhough it works fine for a short amount of countries, it prooves to be super slow with 200 countries
(it takes nearly 15 minutes to process)  and very inefficient as well as it creates a lot of spark tasks.

Furthermore the object obtained afterwards is very slow to process. It takes almost 3 minutes to show 5 rows.

**Is there a smarter way to achieve the same thing in PySpark?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the next year's deaths and year with `lead()` window function. Using them, we can create rest of the columns easily.

```
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('year_n1', func.lead('year').over(wd.partitionBy('country').orderBy('year'))). \
    withColumn('deaths_n1', func.lead('deaths').over(wd.partitionBy('country').orderBy('year'))). \
    filter(func.col('year_n1').isNotNull()). \
    withColumn('period', func.concat_ws('-', func.col('year'), func.col('year_n1'))). \
    withColumn('comparable', 
               func.col('deaths_n1').between(func.col('deaths') * 0.8, func.col('deaths') * 1.2)
               ). \
    select('country', 'period', func.col('deaths').alias('deaths_n'), 'deaths_n1', 'comparable'). \
    show()

# +-------+---------+------+---------+----------+
# |country|   period|deaths|deaths_n1|comparable|
# +-------+---------+------+---------+----------+
# | France|2019-2020|613243|   668922|      true|
# | France|2020-2021|668922|   657000|      true|
# |     UK|2019-2020|530841|   608002|      true|
# +-------+---------+------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: afterwards you just need a small custom filter on the table output
(let's name it `comparableDeaths`):
`cnt_cond = lambda cond: F.sum(F.when(cond, 1).otherwise(0))`
`uncomparable = F.col('comparable') == 'false'`
`uncomparableYearCnt = (comparableDeaths.groupBy('country').agg(cnt_cond(uncomparable).alias('uncomparable')))`
`uncomparableYearCnt.select('country').where('uncomparable = 0').show()`

Comment: is the lambda function converting true/false to 1/0? just cast the boolean field to int to get that.